# Assigning an object attribute in JavaScript changes object in a weird way

Tags: javascript

I'm debugging a complex JS client side framework based on Ext. I stumbled upon a line that gives results that I fail to explain in any way. Here is the line (`me` is actually just an alias for `this`):

```
me.displayTplData = displayTplData;
```

Some values before executing it:

```
me.value: "87172981"
displayTplData: Array[1]  (this is a local variable)
me.displayTplData: undefined
```

After the line (F11, "step into next function call"):

```
me.value: null
displayTplData: Array[1]  (stays as before)
me.displayTplData: null
```

Not only the assignment apparently didn't happen, this also altered value assigned to an unrelated attribute `value`... The only way I could think of is if `displayTplData` has an associated setter (similar to descriptors in Python?). But on the other hand, JS debugger doesn't step into any code when executing the line. Also, this framework works on IE8+, so it certainly doesn't use any recent JS developments.

This happens both with FireFox and Chrome, so it must be some "this is supposed to work this way", but I completely don't understand what's going on.

**Can someone guess what *might* be the reason of it?**  Sorry, I cannot reduce it to a standalone example.

**EDIT:**

Here is the full function, as a context.

```
setValue: function(value, doSelect) {
    var me = this,
        valueNotFoundText = me.valueNotFoundText,
        inputEl = me.inputEl,
        i, len, record,
        dataObj,
        matchedRecords = [],
        displayTplData = [],
        processedValue = [];

    if (me.store.loading) {
        // Called while the Store is loading. Ensure it is processed by the onLoad method.
        me.value = value;
        me.setHiddenValue(me.value);
        return me;
    }

    // This method processes multi-values, so ensure value is an array.
    value = Ext.Array.from(value);

    // Loop through values, matching each from the Store, and collecting matched records
    for (i = 0, len = value.length; i < len; i++) {
        record = value[i];
        if (!record || !record.isModel) {
            record = me.findRecordByValue(record);
        }
        // record found, select it.
        if (record) {
            matchedRecords.push(record);
            displayTplData.push(record.data);
            processedValue.push(record.get(me.valueField));
        }
        // record was not found, this could happen because
        // store is not loaded or they set a value not in the store
        else {
            // If we are allowing insertion of values not represented in the Store, then push the value and
            // create a fake record data object to push as a display value for use by the displayTpl
            if (!me.forceSelection) {
                processedValue.push(value[i]);
                dataObj = {};
                dataObj[me.displayField] = value[i];
                displayTplData.push(dataObj);
                // TODO: Add config to create new records on selection of a value that has no match in the Store
            }
            // Else, if valueNotFoundText is defined, display it, otherwise display nothing for this value
            else if (Ext.isDefined(valueNotFoundText)) {
                displayTplData.push(valueNotFoundText);
            }
        }
    }

    // Set the value of this field. If we are multiselecting, then that is an array.
    me.setHiddenValue(processedValue);
    me.value = me.multiSelect ? processedValue : processedValue[0];
    if (!Ext.isDefined(me.value)) {
        me.value = null;
    }
    me.displayTplData = displayTplData; //store for getDisplayValue method   <------- this is the line
    me.lastSelection = me.valueModels = matchedRecords;

    if (inputEl && me.emptyText && !Ext.isEmpty(value)) {
        inputEl.removeCls(me.emptyCls);
    }

    // Calculate raw value from the collection of Model data
    me.setRawValue(me.getDisplayValue());
    me.checkChange();

    if (doSelect !== false) {
        me.syncSelection();
    }
    me.applyEmptyText();

    return me;
},
```

Comment: search for the string literal `"displayTplData"` in the framework. If it has a setter, then somewhere should be an `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: No, there are no such uses. Actually, `defineProperty` is not used in this framework at all. Is it possible to find out at runtime in the debugger though?

Comment: Neither is `__defineSetter__` used? That is all the ways I know. Sometimes the debugger is buggy, try logging the values to the console before and after the assignment. Also, some code lines of context would be helpful.

Comment: The problem is this was verified in two unrelated debuggers, for Firefox and Chrome. Both give identical results.

Comment: No, the framework doesn't use `__defineSetter__` anywhere either.

Comment: @hege_hegedus An alternative to that function is `Object.defineProperty(me, { set: function ... } );`. You could try searching based on that. The property changes to `null`, which suggests that the action has *some* effect.

Comment: Are you sure you are not debugging a comma expression, and step over runs the whole expression, not only the first part before the first comma?

Comment: @Katana314 I thought it was `Object.defineProperties(me, { displayTplData: { set: function ... } } );`

Comment: @hege_hegedus I suppose both are possible, actually. Good point. Either way, @doublep, it should be possible to view the set operation, if any, by debug-stepping to the `.displayTblData = ` line, and then clicking "Step Into" rather than "Step Over".

Comment: Ok, it seems indeed a weird byproduct of debuggers (both at the same time). I tried to add `console.log(me.value)` both before and after the line and it logs "87172981" as expected. But if I set debugger breakpoint, `me.value` becomes `null` after the line in question. I can't say I understand what's going on anyway, but it seems to be not there when run outside debugger at least.

Comment: @Katana314: I already did that, but it didn't step into anything, just skipped the line as executed. I suspect it might trigger some obscure DOM event with a listener in some way, and that listener sets the value to `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the debugger provides false information. It is strange that both Firefox's and Chrome's debugger produces the same (wrong) inspection, but if you want to be sure about those values, just put `console.log(me.value)` before and after the statement, and see what gets printed.